# What is objc_AssociationPolicy? How does it work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I am new to iOS development. I was learning about associating properties to class. There, I came across objc_AssociationPolicy that is to be used in objc_setAssociatedObject function. It had one parameter objc_AssociationPolicy.

```
enum objc_AssociationPolicy : UInt {
    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN
    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC
    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC
    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN
    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY
}
```

Am I wrong or right?
OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN: this keeps strong reference of the value and value doesn't destroy until the object to which it is associated it destroyed or removed.

OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY: this keeps just a copy of value i.e. no strong reference to value

What about other? What does each case mean? And how does these work? Can anyone explain me with examples?

Answer (score 4):

This is runtime feature from runtime library `<objc/runtime.h>`
 You can use if you wanna add your own property for any class at runtime,  `objc_AssociationPolicy` it's a attributes for this property the same as `assign,copy,retain` (memory management) in property declaration for more info look the [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/)

Answer (score 0):

These are like property attributes which are used in @property declaration.
But in case you cannot declare stored properties (like in categories) and choose objc_setAssociatedObject (a runtime function) then you can use these.